# Get Location in Broadcast Receiver

Tags: android, geolocation, broadcastreceiver, google-play-services

I am using `GooglePlayServices API` to get current location.

In any activity to get current location the following code works perfect

```
@Override
    protected void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        // Connect the client.
        mLocationClient.connect();
    }
  @Override
    protected void onStop() {
        // Disconnecting the client invalidates it.
        mLocationClient.disconnect();
        super.onStop();
    }
```

and the following code gives me Last best Known location of the user.

```
 mCurrentLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
```

But how to ideally connect to and disconnect from location  client in a `BroadcastReceiver` as `onReceive()` is the only method in its Lifecycle?

Comment: Do you want location updates in Broadcast Receiver? Please elaborate your question.

Comment: Hi Vinay i thing the problem is when you have incoming call from someone the Broascast Receiver class will call. Please check when onReceive() method called the check the Internet connection is available or not. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this calls for a service. BroadcastReceivers shouldn't do long operations and the LocationClient looks asynchronous. If you don't want to use a service then maybe an AsyncTask would work, but that would be my second choice.

Comment: I dont want to use Service. AsyncTask solved my problem